# An enumeration of rational s.t. $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(r_n-\frac{1}{n},r_n+\frac{1}{n}\right)\neq \mathbb R$, is it possible?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm doing an old exam of measure theory, and one question is to find an enumeration $\{r_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ of $\mathbb Q$ s.t. $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(r_n-\frac{1}{n},r_n+\frac{1}{n}\right)\neq \mathbb R,$$ 
or in other word s.t. $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(r_n-\frac{1}{n},r_n+\frac{1}{n}\right)\subsetneq \mathbb R. $$

How can this be possible ? I have the impression that if there is such an enumeration, then the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ fails... Indeed, if $x\in\mathbb R$, then there is $x\in \left(r_n-\frac{1}{n},r_n+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: Take your favourite irrational, say $\sqrt2$ and ensure that any rational near
it occurs late on in the enumeration of irrationals.

Comment: And if you want to seek for an extreme, for each $\alpha > 2$ you can choose $(r_n)$ in such a way that the union $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B(r_n,1/n)$ has Lebesgue measure less than $\alpha$.

Comment: In fact such union can cover R is difficult to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there exist enumerations $\{r_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that 
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(r_n-\frac{1}{n},r_n+\frac{1}{n}\right)\subsetneq \mathbb R.$$

For example take an enumeration $\{r_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that the rational numbers in $[0,M]$ have indices in $\{m^k\}_{k\geq 1}$ where $m$ and $M$ are integers $\geq 3$. 
It should be easy to verify that for such enumeration, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(r_n-\frac{1}{n},r_n+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is NOT the whole real line because a non-empty subset in $(0,M)$ remains uncovered.

Comment: Better stretch that a little - if $-0.1$ has index $2$ and $1.1$ has index $1$, that'll cover the interval.

Comment: Yes, but I left open the choice of $m$.

Comment: The problem is that we can cover the interval without using any of the rationals inside it. You need a wider interval.

Comment: @jmerry I think that now the hint works.

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Comment: @jmerry BTW thanks for your useful comments.